# Adding facebook birthday information to some model in rails / devise / omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

I had problems getting the birthday information from facebook into my app.
Biggest problem was misunderstanding the permissions page from FB:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Here the birthday is described as user_birthday. But thats not how you can grab it from the response. I found a solution which is very easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting the birthday from facebok is easy if you have a method like

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
unless user
  user = User.create!(
                       provider:auth.provider,
                       uid:auth.uid,
                       email:auth.info.email,

                       password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                       )
    @player = Player.new
    @player = Date.strptime(auth.extra.raw_info.birthday,'%m/%d/%Y')
    @player.save
end
user
end
```

The key part here is to strptime from the right array, which is not user_birthday, but just birthday. Also ensure that you have set the user_birthday as permission in devise.rb -> Else you will only receive nil.